# After brew install of python@3.9 "python" is no longer found

Tags: python

`python3` is available after:

```
brew install python@3.9
```

But there is no `python` to be found. Not in `/usr/local/bin` or in `/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.16/bin`.  There are many programs that look for plain old `python` so what is supposed to be done here?

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal and type:

```
python3 --version
```

just to be sure that python is installled. In many modern operating systems, `python` refers to Python 2.x, which is an outdated version of Python that is no longer supported. So you should either use python3 command or to create alias for `python` to point to `python3`:

```
alias python='python3'
```

Comment: `python3 -V` comes up with 3.9.16 as expected.  I'm supposed to add `python` alias  manually?

Comment: yes. also you will probably need to add python to PATH. check the instructions [here](https://realpython.com/add-python-to-path/)